# Angular initialise connection before opening app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I am just beginning to understand Angular(?) and am trying to build an app with GameSparks as data provider (SDK)

I have an Router in my project like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: '../pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    loadChildren: '../pages/list/list.module#ListPageModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,  { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now, I have added the GameSparks SDK to my project in the "scr/assets/gamesparks" folder.

In here I have a initialise .js script like this:

```
var gamesparks = new GameSparks();

var gsKey = "XXXXXXXXX";
var gsSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var gsCredentials = "";

var isLive = true; 

//Initialse the SDK
function init() {

    if (isLive) {
        gamesparks.initLive({
            key: gsKey,
            secret: gsSecret,
            //credential: gsCredentials,
            onNonce: onNonce,
            onInit: onInit,
            onMessage: onMessage,
            logger: console.log,
        });
    } else {
        gamesparks.initPreview({
            key: gsKey,
            secret: gsSecret,
            //credential: gsCredentials,
            onNonce: onNonce,
            onInit: onInit,
            onMessage: onMessage,
            logger: console.log,
        });
    }

}

//Callback function to hmac sha256 a nonce with the secret. It's assumed you will have your own method of securing the secret;
function onNonce(nonce) {
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(nonce, gsSecret));
}

//Callback to handle when the SDK is initialised and ready to go
function onInit() {
    console.log("Initialised");
    // NOW I AM READY TO START THE APP, BUT NOT SURE HOW?!?!
}
```

When onInit() is called I should be able to move forward, but i am not sure how to call this script before the router or if it is even there I should be focusing on, and how do I make the GameSparks SDK available in all my pages?

Really hope for some guidance or help and thanks in advance :-)

/**************** EDIT ******************/

Did what Rui suggested, like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

var gamesparks = new GameSparks();

var gsKey = "XXXXXXXXXX";
var gsSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var gsCredentials = "";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GamesparksService {

  isLive = false;

  init() {

    if (this.isLive) {
        gamesparks.initLive({
            key: gsKey,
            secret: gsSecret,
            //credential: gsCredentials,
            onNonce: this.onNonce,
            onInit: this.onInit,
            onMessage: this.onMessage,
            logger: console.log,
        });
    } else {
        gamesparks.initPreview({
            key: gsKey,
            secret: gsSecret,
            //credential: gsCredentials,
            onNonce: this.onNonce,
            onInit: this.onInit,
            onMessage: this.onMessage,
            logger: console.log,
        });
    }

  }

  //Callback function to hmac sha256 a nonce with the secret. It's assumed you will have your own method of securing the secret;
  onNonce(nonce) {
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(nonce, gsSecret));
  }

  //Callback to handle when the SDK is initialised and ready to go
  onInit() {
    console.log("Initialised");
  }

  //Callback to handle async messages from the gamesparks platform
  onMessage(message) {
    console.log("onMessage: " + JSON.stringify(message["scriptData"]));
  }

}
```

Now I have some other issues.
This script is called gamesparks.service.ts and is the folder "./app/services/"

Now, my GameSparks .js files are in the "./assets/gamesparks/" folder.

In the above script, var gamesparks = new GameSparks(); has a red underline beneath "GameSparks()" and so does "CryptoJS".?!?

How do I refer to this in the service script?

Hoping for help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about put your GameSparks init code into a service class, init it in constructor, and expose the GameSparks with a getter, and inject the service into the component you want to use.